# How to apply the output of numpy.argpartition for 2-D Arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, indexing

I have a largish 2d numpy array, and I want to extract the lowest 10 elements of each row as well as their indexes. Since my array is largish, I would prefer not to sort the whole array.

I heard about the `argpartition()` function, with which I can get the indexes of the lowest 10 elements:

```
top10indexes = np.argpartition(myBigArray,10)[:,:10]
```

Note that `argpartition()` partitions axis -1 by default, which is what I want. The result here has the same shape as myBigArray containing indexes into the respective rows such that the first 10 indexes point to the 10 lowest values.

**How can I now extract the elements of `myBigArray` corresponding to those indexes?**

Obvious fancy indexing like `myBigArray[top10indexes]` or `myBigArray[:,top10indexes]` do something quite different. I could also use list comprehensions, something like:

```
array([row[idxs] for row,idxs in zip(myBigArray,top10indexes)])
```

but that would incur a performance hit iterating numpy rows and converting the result back to an array.

nb: I could just use `np.partition()` to get the values, and they may even correspond to the indexes (or may not..), but I don't want to do the partition twice if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can avoid using the flattened copies and the need to extract all the values by doing:

```
num = 10
top = np.argpartition(myBigArray, num, axis=1)[:, :num]
myBigArray[np.arange(myBigArray.shape[0])[:, None], top]
```

For NumPy >= 1.9.0 this will be very efficient and comparable to `np.take()`.

Comment: I deleted my answer using `flatten()`. I worked out why it didn't work, but couldn't see any easy way to fix it without effectively making a more convoluted version of yours!

Comment: gr8! I also learned that `None` plays the same role here as `newaxis`:)  btw, `arr` in your answer should be `myBigArray` in case my edit is not accepted..